# How to append column onto csv on the fly

Tags: python, parsing, csv, append, python-itertools

I am trying to read the first column of my CSV, run a web-service using this column, take the output from this and append it to my CSV. I'd like to do this on a line-by-line basis.

Here is what I have come up with so far :

```
loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter='\n')
with open('FinalCSV.csv','rb') as tsvin, open('FinalCSV.csv', 'a+b') as csvout:
    tsvin = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,0])
    writer = csv.writer(csvout)
    count = 0
    for row in csvout:
        sep = '|'
        row = row.split(sep, 1)[0]
        cmd = subprocess.Popen("python GetJustAlexaRanking.py " + row ,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=True)
        (output, err) = cmd.communicate()
        exit_code = cmd.wait()
        outlist = output.split('\r\n')
        try:
          outrank1 = outlist[1][outlist[1].index(':')+1:]
        except ValueError:
          outrank1 = "?"
        row.append(str(outrank1).rstrip()) #writing,error here 
        print [str(outlist[0]).rstrip(), str(outrank1).rstrip()]
        count+=1
```

However this is giving me the error that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File.py", line 28, in <module>
    row.append(str(outrank1).rstrip()) #writing,error here
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How can I accomplish what I wish to do?

Edit :

```
loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter='\n')
with open('FinalCSV.csv','rb') as tsvread, open('FinalCSVFin.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
    tsvin = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,0])
    writer = csv.writer(csvout)
    count = 0
    for row in tsvread:
        sep = '|'
        row = row.split(sep, 1)[0]
        cmd = subprocess.Popen("python GetJustAlexaRanking.py " + row ,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=True)
        (output, err) = cmd.communicate()
        exit_code = cmd.wait()
        outlist = output.split('\r\n')
        try:
          outrank1 = outlist[1][outlist[1].index(':')+1:]
        except ValueError:
          outrank1 = "?"
        row = [row, outrank1.rstrip()]
        writer.writerow(row)
        print [str(outlist[0]).rstrip(), str(outrank1).rstrip()]
        count+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `row` is not a list, but a string:

```
row = row.split(sep, 1)[0]
```

You then use that string in a `subprocess` command.

You'll need to make it a list again; instead of `append`, use:

```
row = [row, outrank1.rstrip()]
```

where `outrank1` is always a string anyway, no need to call `str()` on it.

Note that if you are trying to both read from and write to the `csvout` file handle, you'll have to be very careful about your read-write position. You cannot just write to a file handle and hope to replace existing data for example. Best to use a separate, new file to write to and have that replace the old file location by moving one over the other.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I have edited my code above to show what I am currently running with your changes. Although the code will now run, it does not append a column to my output (and in fact makes no difference to the output file). Any suggestions? Thank you :)

Comment: Apologies, I copied the wrong text there! I have updated it now; it is now running but eventually fails due to an IndexError. It is also printing my output in the incorrect format as can be seen here : http://i.imgur.com/borLltB.png . Thanks you very much for your help!:)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4uwgxPk.png shows better why the issue is occuring  - seems to be an extra carriage return and quotation marks in the output.

Comment: Without details as to what your input sources produce this is hard to diagnose.

Comment: My input source is a csv, with four columns. I have pasted up an extract here : http://pastebin.com/3HRGAP7Z . I just want to run my webservice and add a column with the output on a line-by-line basis but as a newbie to Python I am finding it really hard. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: I'll have to look tomorrow; sorry!